# UI Router params exception

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to create a structure for creating, reading, updating and destroying that consists on indenting params:

```
/items/create
/items/1/view || /items/1/edit || /items/1/remove
```

The states for those are like this in `$stateProvider`:

```
.state('items.create', {
  url: '/create',
  templateUrl: 'item/create.html'
})
.state('items.item', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/:_id',
  templateUrl: 'item/itembody.html'
})
.state('items.item.view', {
  url: '/view',
  templateUrl: 'item/item.html'
})
.state('items.item.edit', [... and so on ...]
```

I'm also redirecting `/1` to `/1/view` using `$urlRouterProvider`:

```
.when('/items/:_id', '/items/:_id/view');
```

Problem is when trying to reach `/items/create` I'm being redirected to `/items/create/view`. Is there a way to protect or make an exception to this word so I can reach its URL?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that the **urls** are being combined, like so:

> Appended Routes (default)
>
> When using url routing together with nested states the default behavior is for child states to append their url to the urls of each of its parent states.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('contacts', {
     url: '/contacts',
     ...
  })
  .state('contacts.list', {
     url: '/list',
     ...
  });
```

> So the routes would become:
>
> 'contacts' state matches "/contacts"
>
> 'contacts.list' state matches "/contacts/list". The urls were combined.

Try using different state names.

Answer (score 0):

This is a syntax error, change this `url: '/item/:_id.view'` for this `url: '/item/:_id'`.

Comment: Sorry about that. It's a typo that doesn't solve the problem